# Enumerate environment with M1, M2, ... \(m_1\), \(m_2\)

Tags: enumerate

May the enumerate environment be altered so that the rows are named e.g. M1, M2 ..., or $m_1$, $m_2$ ..., and in such a way that we may use \label{Mi} so that \ref{Mi} produces Mi, while \ref{mi} to \label{mi} produces (m_i)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course, with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Look at item \ref{M2}.

\begin{enumerate}[label=($\mathrm{M}_{\arabic*}$),ref=$\mathrm{M}_{\arabic*}$]
\item Something
\item\label{M2} Something else
\item Again
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]